# NodeJS hmac digest issue with accents

Tags: node.js, hmac

I'm doing a side by side comparison with Ruby, PHP and NodeJS for the following code, getting an incorrect response in NodeJS using the `crypto` module.

**PHP**

```
hash_hmac('sha256', 'text', 'á');
```

**Ruby**

```
OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha256', 'á', 'text')
```

**NodeJS**

```
var signer = crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'á');
var expected = signer.update("text").digest('hex');
```

Both Ruby and PHP return `34b3ba4ea7e8ff214f2f36b31c6a6d88cfbf542e0ae3b98ba6c0203330c9f55b`, while, NodeJS returns `7dc85acba66d21e4394be4f8ead2a327c9f1adc64a99c710c98f60c425bd7411`. I noticed that, if I try with `utf8_encode('á')` in PHP, it actually gives me the result Node expects.

I'm loading the accented text in Node from a file, like so:

```js
JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('keys.js', 'utf8'));
```

How would I go about changing my code in Node to get the resulting hash that both PHP and Ruby  present?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of node? Running your sample code under node v0.6.11, I get your expected result.

Comment: I have Node 0.6.11 as well, on OSX 10.7 but `7dc85acba66d21e4394be4f8ead2a327c9f1adc64a99c710c98f60c425bd7411` is NOT the expected result.

Comment: Sure thing, I get `34b3ba4ea7e8ff214f2f36b31c6a6d88cfbf542e0ae3b98ba6c0203330c9f55b` (on Ubuntu, my locale is `en_US.UTF-8`).

Comment: Sorry - I got the expected but only after copy-pasting your source code above, munging the `à` in the process. I get `Ã¡` in my source code, and that yields your expected result (`34b3ba4ea7e8ff214f2f36b31c6a6d88cfbf542e0ae3b98ba6c0203330c9f55b`). How are ruby and php doing this, is it utf8 or some other encoding?

Comment: That is weird, neither in OSX nor Ubuntu, both with the same `en_US.UTF-8` locale, did I get that hash.

Comment: It is UTF-8, my guess is it has something to do with the way I load the file and how it gets parsed. Weird thing is, when I `console.log(theKey)`, I see the output correctly as `á`.

Comment: Honestly I think your Ruby and PHP implementations don't have a UTF-8 string. That's why PHP `utf8_encode` works. That's why `Ã¡` in Node.js gives the same result as `à` in Ruby & PHP.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This code will give you the correct result:

```js
var crypto = require('crypto');

var signer = crypto.createHmac('sha256', new Buffer('á', 'utf8'));
var result = signer.update("text").digest('hex');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, this actually works! Could you help me out to figure out why so?

Comment: crypto.createHmac is a binding to C++ library. Issue occurs when converting JavaScript string to C++ char*. This is repeated for all non-single-byte characters. Buffer can do this conversion correctly.