# Github push event signature don't match

Tags: javascript, github, webhooks, github-api

I'm coding a [Webhook for GitHub](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/), and implemented secure verification in `KOA.js` as:

```js
function sign(tok, blob) {
  var hmac;

  hmac = crypto
    .createHmac('sha1', tok)
    .update(blob)
    .digest('hex');

  return 'sha1=' + hmac;
}

...

key = this.request.headers['x-hub-signature'];
blob = JSON.stringify(this.request.body);

if (!key || !blob) {
  this.status = 400;
  this.body = 'Bad Request';
}

lock = sign(settings.api_secret, blob);

if (lock !== key) {
  console.log(symbols.warning, 'Unauthorized');
  this.status = 403;
  this.body = 'Unauthorized';
  return;
}

...
```

for pull_requests and create events this works ok, even pushing new branches works, but for push commits events the `x-hub-signature` and the computed hash from the payload don't match, so it always get 403 unauthorized.

**Update**

I've noticed that for this kind of push payloads the commits and head_commit are added to the payload. I've tried removing the commits and the head_commit from the body but it didn't work.

**Update**

For more information please review these example payloads. I've also included url for the test repo and token info: https://gist.github.com/marcoslhc/ec581f1a5ccdd80f8b33

Comment: What does "fails miserably" mean? What error(s) do you get?

Comment: The 'x-hub-signature' doesn't equals to the calculated hash.

Comment: A total stab in the dark, but are you sure that `this.request.body` is not already a string? If it is, it will be double-encoded (e.g., the three-character string `foo` will be JSON encoded into the five-character string `"foo"`). See what `typeof this.request.body` produces.

Comment: Are you able to provide a sample problematic event payload (from the events API), the value of `x-hub-signature`, your calculated HMAC, and the secret?  Obviously this would want to be from a test repository.

Comment: You can see example data along with token details here: https://gist.github.com/marcoslhc/ec581f1a5ccdd80f8b33

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [default encoding of Crypto hash.update() is binary](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_update_data_input_encoding) as detailed in the answer to [Node JS crypto, cannot create hmac on chars with accents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195480/node-js-crypto-cannot-create-hmac-on-chars-with-accents).  This causes a problem in your push-event payload, which contains the character `U+00E1` *LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE* in `Hernández` four times, and GitHub services is hashing the payload as `utf-8` encoded.  Note that your Gist shows these incorrectly-encoded in ISO-8859-1, so also make sure that you are handling the incoming request character-encoding properly (but this should happen by-default).

To fix this you need to either use a `Buffer`:

```
hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', tok).update(new Buffer(blob, 'utf-8')).digest('hex');
```

... or pass the encoding directly to `update`:

```
hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', tok).update(blob, 'utf-8').digest('hex');
```

The correct hash of `7f9e6014b7bddf5533494eff6a2c71c4ec7c042d` will then be calculated.

Comment: Ok. Going to try :) Makes perfect sense now!

Comment: Flag should be `utf8` not `utf-8`

Comment: @JosephLust thanks, perhaps, but either should work fine - console.log(Buffer.isEncoding('utf-8'));
true
console.log(Buffer.isEncoding('utf8'));
true