# node-postgres UTF password bug

Tags: node.js, postgresql, unicode, node-postgres

I'm using https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres `pg` module. Apparently I can't consume a Unicode password to connect to the db. From the same location `psql` with connection parameters goes OK. With Node.js, it gives ne `password authentication failed for user`. When I check with `console.log()` I see exactly what I expect. If I change a password to ASCII both in the db and the connection string, everything works well. But I need the old Unicode password to be consumed...

I tried both https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client

`new pg.Client({...password: Código`

and

`conString = "postgres://...Código@"`

I know that both ODBC (`Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE};`) and JDBC (`;Unicode=true`) support UTF in connection string. I find nothing on Node.js `pg` module UTF support.

Please help.

I saw http://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/ and read the documentation on https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres. Please help with the question.

Thank you!

Comment: would https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv be helpful?..

Comment: @brianc would you please have a look?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a bug in `/lib/client.js`: `crypto.createHash('md5').update('утфUTF').digest('hex')` gives:

> a77b17c858d93bf7455211a629df45f8

while the right md5 would be:

```
a=#select md5('утфutf');
               md5
----------------------------------
 6dbfa2a80226f7629e537268b0650898
(1 row)
```

So `crypto.createHash('md5').update('утфutf', 'utf-8').digest('hex')` gives

> 6dbfa2a80226f7629e537268b0650898

Following that

> The default encoding used by the crypto module is usually 'binary' from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12196252/5315974)

Fixed my utf password problem. So I created PR - maybe soon it won't be a question anymore.

https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/pull/1178