# pg-promise UTF connection string

Tags: node.js, postgresql, utf-8, pg-promise

pg-promise does not understand UTF passwords?.. I can't make it work with them. Tried on linux and osx, postgres 9.3, 9.5 - seems to be not specific to versions. Looked into code. pg-promise uses [pg](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres), which uses [pg-connect-string](https://github.com/iceddev/pg-connection-string) which is build based on back [pg](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres). Can't find the the root of the problem. Please help.

### code to reproduce:

```
MacBook-Air:js vao$ cat 2.js
```

> ```
> var pgp = require("pg-promise")();
> var cs = 'postgresql://utf:утф@127.0.0.1:5433/a';
> var db = pgp(cs);
> db.connect()
>     .then(function (obj) {
>         obj.done(); // success, release the connection;
>     })
>     .catch(function (error) {
>         console.log("ERROR:", error.message || error);
>     });
> console.log(cs);
> ```

### returns:

```
MacBook-Air:js vao$ node 2.js
```

> ```
> postgresql://utf:утф@127.0.0.1:5433/a
> ERROR: password authentication failed for user "utf"
> ```

### Using same connection string with `psql`:

```
MacBook-Air:js vao$ psql 'postgresql://utf:утф@127.0.0.1:5433/a'
```

> ```
> psql (9.5.3)
> Type "help" for help.
>
> a=> \q
> ```

### Trying bad password deliberately with same connection string:

```
MacBook-Air:js vao$ psql 'postgresql://utf:утфWrongPassword@127.0.0.1:5433/a'
```

> ```
> psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "utf"
> MacBook-Air:js vao$
> ```

Comment: it appeared to be a bug. answered own question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41005963/5315974

Answer (score 0):

As the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), I'd like at least to offer some guidance here on where to look, not the exact answer, as I've never dealt with UTF passwords myself.

[pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) uses [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres), which in turn uses [pg-connection-string](https://github.com/iceddev/pg-connection-string) to parse the connection. If there is an issue, then it is most likely inside [pg-connection-string](https://github.com/iceddev/pg-connection-string).

I would recommend trying Unicode notation that relies on `%`. Maybe it will work. Maybe not, I've never tried. Also the following question was never answered: [Node.js postgres UTF connect string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935749/node-js-postgres-utf-connect-string), which isn't reassuring either.

Sorry, I cannot be of more help at present.

Comment: It's a bug of node-postgres. Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/41005963/5315974 if you interested